# CS50x Caesar - Segmentation fault when inserting isalpha(argv[1])

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50, caesar-cipher

For the CS50x Problem Caesar I have created a program that encrypts messages using Caesar’s cipher.

For this, the program must recognize that a command-line argument is only a number. So no two or more numbers, no number below zero, and no text.

But as soon as I add the check if it is a text with `|| isalpha(argv[1])`, the program does not work anymore.

The terminal prints the following when I try to run the program:

> `Segmentation fault`

Can anyone tell me what is the problem with the code

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    int kkey = 0;

    // Check if correct command-line arguments
    if (argc != 2 || atoi(argv[1]) < 0 || isalpha(argv[1])) //segfault here
    {
        printf("./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        kkey = atoi(argv[1]);
    }

    // Ask for Plaintext to encrypt
    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");

    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(plaintext); i < n; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(plaintext[i]) && islower(plaintext[i]))
        {
            plaintext[i] = (plaintext[i] - 'a' + kkey) % 26 + 97;
        }
        else if (isalpha(plaintext[i]) && isupper(plaintext[i]))
        {
            plaintext[i] = (plaintext[i] - 'A' + kkey) % 26 + 65;
        }

        printf("%c", plaintext[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should enable warnings in your compiler. Then read them and handle them! If you don't understand them, read what `isalpha` is expecting as parameter. Hint: It does not expect to get a pointer to a string.

Comment: Not related: Don't use magic numbers. If you mean `'a'`, write `'a'`, not `97`.

Comment: `argv[1]` is a _string_, but `isalpha` requires a char. You are asking whether the memory address of `argv[1]` is alpha. That is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As said by @Gerhardh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63483086/cs50x-caesar-segmentation-fault-when-inserting-isalphaargv1/63483657#comment112257360_63483086), you can't use strings as argument of `isalpha`, you need a loop to check each character of the string.

In any case that is not the best approach, using a negated `isdigit` would be a better option, because it accounts for all the other non numeric characters.

```
//...
// Check if correct command-line arguments
if (argc != 2 || atoi(argv[1]) < 0) 
{
    printf("./caesar key\n");
    return 1;
}

for(size_t i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++){
    if(!isdigit(argv[1][i])){ //if one of the characters is not a digit 0-9
        puts("./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
}

kkey = atoi(argv[1]); //no else needed
//...
```

---

**Note that `atoi` will invoke undefined behavior if the converted value is not representable by an `int`.**

You can use [`strtol`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) for a more robust alternative.

The link is for Linux man page which I find quite nice, but this is cross-platform.

---

Again, [as stated by @Gerhardh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63483086/cs50x-caesar-segmentation-fault-when-inserting-isalphaargv1/63483657#comment112257450_63483086), using character codes may backfire, in this case you are using ASCII encoding, but there are others, this makes your code less portable, use the character instead, `26 + 'a'` and `26 + 'A'`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I realized the problem with the data types. Now the program runs as wished.